# UIScrollView in UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am trying to add a `UIScrollView()` into one of my table's cells. I am having difficulties figuring out in what methods to put the code for the scroll view.

I have a scroll view elsewhere in my app, and this is the code I used transferred across to my `UITableView()` view as I guessed it should be:

```
var page = Int()
var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
var sixPlusImages = [
    UIImage(named: "Glance 5.5"),
    UIImage(named: "Currencies 5.5"),
    UIImage(named: "Swipe 5.5"),
    UIImage(named: "Format 5.5"),
    UIImage(named: "Search 5.5")
]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:AppImagesTableViewCell = self.appTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("appImages", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppImagesTableViewCell

    return cell
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    let cell = appTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: 0))

    if page < 0 || page >= pageViews.count {
        return
    }

    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        return
    } else {
        var imageFrame = CGRect(x: (cell.scrollView.bounds.width * CGFloat(page)) + 5, y: 0, width: (cell.scrollView.bounds.width) - 10, height: 40)

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = imageFrame
        imageView.image = sixPlusImages[page]
        cell.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    pageViews[page] = imageView
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= sixPlusImages.count {
        return
    }

    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }
}

func loadVisiblePages() {
    let pageWidth = cell.scrollView.frame.size.width
    page = Int(floor((cell.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

    pageControl.currentPage = page

    let firstPage = page - 1
    let lastPage = page + 1

    for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    for index in firstPage...lastPage {
        loadPage(index)
    }

    for var index = lastPage+1; index < sixPlusImages.count; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadVisiblePages()
}
```

Obviously, there are quite a few issues with it. I don't seem to be able to access the scrollView that I have as an outlet in the cell class, which is causing some issues.

Can anyone give me some guidance? There aren't any Swift examples online that I could see.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you are using part of the code proposed in the tutorials in [UIScrollView Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) to make a slide show using an `UIScrollView`.

You can use an `UIScrollView` inside you custom `UITableViewCell` without any problem, first of all you have to declare your `@IBOutlet` inside the `CustomTableViewCell`.

The class `CustomTableViewCell` must be implement the protocol `UIScrollViewDelegate` to be notified it about changes in the `UIScrollView`, you must implement the functions to handle the `UIScrollView` inside it. Let's take a look in the following example:

> **CustomTableViewCell** to handle the `UIScrollView`

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {


   @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

   var pageImages: [UIImage] = []
   var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []


   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()        

      // 1
      pageImages = [UIImage(named: "photo1.jpg")!,
         UIImage(named: "photo2.jpg")!,
         UIImage(named: "photo3.jpg")!]            

      let pageCount = pageImages.count       

      // 3
      for _ in 0..<pageCount {
          pageViews.append(nil)
      }

      // 4
      let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
      scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count),
        height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

      // 5
      loadVisiblePages()        
  }

  func loadPage(page: Int) {
       if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
          // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
          return
       }

       // 1
       if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
          // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
       } else {
          // 2
          var frame = scrollView.bounds
          frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
          frame.origin.y = 0.0

          // 3
          let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
          newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
          newPageView.frame = frame
          scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)

          // 4
          pageViews[page] = newPageView
       }
   }

   func loadVisiblePages() {
      // First, determine which page is currently visible
      let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
      let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

      // Work out which pages you want to load
      let firstPage = page - 1
      let lastPage = page + 1

      // Purge anything before the first page
      for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
         purgePage(index)
      }

      // Load pages in our range
      for index in firstPage...lastPage {
         loadPage(index)
      }

      // Purge anything after the last page
      for var index = lastPage+1; index < pageImages.count; ++index {
         purgePage(index)
      }
   }

   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      // Load the pages that are now on screen
      loadVisiblePages()
   }

   func purgePage(page: Int) {
       if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
          // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
         return
       }

       // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
       if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
          pageView.removeFromSuperview()
          pageViews[page] = nil
       }
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

      // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your `UITableViewController` or `ViewController` the only thing you need is the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell        

    return cell
}
```

The above code it's only for example, you must consider the constraints for the `UIScrollView`, enable the Paging Enabled, etc.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried out that code (obviously first changing the variables to my own), and it compiles, but nothing is displayed in the table. Just an empty cell.

Comment: I can share the project if you want it, by github

Comment: Have you set the images for your own isn't?

Comment: Yup, my images are set correctly. I'm going through the code at the moment to see if I can spot any differences.

Comment: Also, the scroll view doesn't just scroll horizontally, but can be dragged in any direction? I can't figure out why, since the other scroll view I have doesn't do this. I'll post a separate question with my current issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757752/issues-with-uiscrollview-in-uitableview-cell

Comment: @user3746428 I have answered your question here, I'll try to answer the other one too.

Comment: Finally figured it out. It didn't like the fact that I had spaces in the image name. Works fine now! One more question, I would like the images to be displayed side by side (like they are in app store screenshots). How could I do this?

Comment: It works! Now, I would like to load the images from a URL and the url is passed from the previous view controller, on the navigation stack. I can't figure out how to send data to the awakeFromNib method?