# Issues with UIScrollView in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I have been trying to add a scroll view to my table view's cell, but have been running into issues with the images being missing. The pages in the scroll view seem to be loading correctly (based on the debug view hierarchy), but none of the images are showing.

Here is my code:

```
class AppImagesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
var sixPlusImages: [UIImage?] = []

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    sixPlusImages = [
        UIImage(named: "Glance 5.5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "Currencies 5.5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "Swipe 5.5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "Format 5.5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "Search 5.5.png")
    ]

    let pageCount = sixPlusImages.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount

    for _ in 0..<pageCount {
        pageViews.append(nil)
    }

    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(sixPlusImages.count), height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    loadVisiblePages()
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= sixPlusImages.count {
        return
    }

    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
    } else {
        var frame = scrollView.bounds
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0

        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: sixPlusImages[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = frame
        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)

        pageViews[page] = newPageView
    }
}

func loadVisiblePages() {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

    let firstPage = page - 1
    let lastPage = page + 1

    for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    for index in firstPage...lastPage {
        loadPage(index)
    }

    for var index = lastPage+1; index < sixPlusImages.count; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    pageControl.currentPage = page
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadVisiblePages()
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= sixPlusImages.count {
        return
    }

    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

And here is what the view hierarchy looks like:

[image]

Also, the scroll view allows me to scroll in any direction, rather than just horizontally as it should. I can't see why it does this, as the other scroll view I use, doesn't do this.

Anyone see any issues?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: I actually just figured it out, finally. I'm not, but the problem was that it didn't like the fact that I had spaces in the image names. I do have another question though - How can I make the images appear side by side like they do, for example, in the app store screenshots?